# Lifts Preserve Smoothness (especially Flatness)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, deformation-theory

Following question arised from following former thread of mine:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335971/theorem-from-deformation-theory?noredirect=1#comment846826_335971

I think that I have *nearly* found the solution but I'm quite unsure if this works and how generally. Therefore I would be glad if someboby could look through the following argument and examine if it works:

The problem is the following:

Assume $B$ a ring with an ideal $I$ such that $I^2=0$. Denote $B_0:=B/I$. Let $g_1, ..., g_r \in B_0[T_1,..., T_n]$ are polynomials and denote by $f_i $ arbitrary lift of $g_i$ in  $B_0[T_1,..., T_n]$.

Assume that $g: B_0 \to B_0[T_1,...,T_n]/(g_1,...,g_r)$ is smooth (especially flat).

The question is if the induced morphism

$f: B \to B[T_1,...,T_n]/(f_1,...,f_r)$ induced by lifts $f_i$ of $g_i$ from above ***stays also smooth*** (especially flat)?

My idea was to use Jacobian smoothness condition: the (4) from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_morphism#Equivalent_definitions

Since $g$ smooth $B_0[T_1,...,T_n]/(g_1,...,g_r)$ is generated by $r \times r$-minors of matrix $(\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial T_j})$.

So the question is if always $B[T_1,...,T_n]/(f_1,...,f_r)$ is generated by $r \times r$-minors of matrix $(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j})$.

This would of course mean that all such lifts preserves smoothness. I'm not sure if the story is here so simple.

For example I don't see the point where the assumption $I^2$ play role.

Comment: Hint: Smoothness is Zariski open on the base

Comment: @user45878:Denote $B[T_1,...,T_n]/(f_1,...,f_r):=A$. Your observation tells me that if $p$ is a prime of $B$ and $A \otimes B/p$ (=fiber) is smooth over $B/p$ then there exist an $b \in B$ and open neighbourhood $D(b) \subset Spec(B)$ such that $B_b[T_1,...,T_n]/(f_1,...,f_r)$ (remark:$B_b$:= localisation at $b$) is smooth over $B_b$, right?

Comment: hmmm I'm not sure if I understood your argument correctly; lets try. Take a prime $p$ with $I \subset p$. By assumption $g: B_0:= B/I \to B_0[T_1,...,T_n]/(g_1,...,g_r)$ was smooth and smoothness is preserved by base change; we change base via $B/I \to B/p$ then $B/p \to B/p[T_1,...,T_n]/(g_1,...,g_r)$ is smooth and by your hint $B_b \to B_b[T_1,...,T_n]/(f_1,...,f_r)$ is also smooth. Is ***this*** the argument you have in mind? Or was my attempt to use your hint too circumstaneous?